# Facebook audience network ads not showing

Tags: java, android, facebook, ads

I'm trying to integrate facebook ads , i followed all the documentation and it's not working

Manifists

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        AudienceNetworkAds.initialize(this);


        facebookAdView = new com.facebook.ads.AdView(this,"732965463811239_733275773780208", AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);

        LinearLayout adContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.banner_container);

        // Add the ad view to your activity layout
        adContainer.addView(facebookAdView);

        // Request an ad
        facebookAdView.loadAd();

    }
```

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. *it's not working* isnt a working problem description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding
 AdSettings.addTestDevice("808a2024-66bb-4d52-9804-3c905991f2b3");

Answer (score 5):

For Your Test Facebook ads you Banner id is

```
facebookAdView = new com.facebook.ads.AdView
(this,"IMG_16_9_APP_INSTALL#732965463811239_733275773780208, 
AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);
```